# Need a jquery plugin similar to extplorer

Tags: jquery-plugins, extjs

Can someone pls point me to any jquery plugin for a file/folder browser similar to the extplorer ub ExtJS with tree hierarchy along with the grid and list view in the right pane:

http://extplorer.sourceforge.net/extplorer.png

Answer (score 0):

[jQuery File Tree](http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/03/jquery-file-tree/) is close to what you need.

Comment: Thanks Alex, but I also need a right pane with the sub-folders and files list and grid view.